# Dropdown with submenu Issue

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a drop down with sub-menu ,
    but due to some `css` error I am unable to fix the issue, 
    can anybody help me with proper solutions.

Comment: we cant help without any code.. create a demo, we can try :)

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/sZIng.jpg

Comment: @wajidullahKhan: please show us any code, not image.

Comment: create a demo in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Amit https://jsfiddle.net/psrmy4oy/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `left:0; and top:.. px` according to your need like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/psrmy4oy/2/)**

```
.menu li:hover ul {
display:block;
width:200px;
list-style:none;
height:auto;
border:1px solid #ccc;
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:38px;
```

}

Edit:  Try like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/psrmy4oy/4/)**

```
.menu li > a:hover {
    background:#09C;
    border-radius:5px;
}

.menu li:hover ul {
    display:block;
    width:200px;
    list-style:none;
    height:auto;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:37px;
}
```

Hope this is what you want!

Comment: @ Amit, the main problem is of padding in submenu, can u pls hv a look of image and code what I have posted

Comment: Yes dear, its working absolutely fine, thanks a lot dear